# Data encrypted on iPad/iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ipad, encryption

is the data stored on an iPad/iPhone encrypted?
I assume that the iPad/iPhone has an advanced pass code (not just the 4-digit code).
So my question is if data that my custom app stores in the device is encrypted or not (if no special methods are taken in the source code of the app). Would an attacker be able to read the data? What if he jailbreaks the device?

Thanks!

Comment: [This](https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/core-data-and-enterprise-iphone-applications-protecting-your-data/) might be worth reading. But honestly, if somebody really wants to read your data, he is probably going to find a way. My company has a policy to never store client sensitive data on the device.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no if you don't apply any encrypting technique on it. You can try to use iExplorer to browse all the sandboxes of your device's applications. You may get surprised about the security of many apps out there.

Comment: So if an attacker (how does not know the passcode) jailbreaks the iPad and then installs iExplorer, then he can read all data of my custom app (and probably als emails)? Is that correct?

Comment: Not really that, iExplorer is a Mac application. Even you don't have to jailbreak the phone. You only need to have the phone with you and that should be enough for the rest. I haven't tried iExplorer with a locked iPhone so I can't tell...

Answer (score 0):

I am just starting getting familiar with security in iOS, but from what I read and understood from  [Apple's IOS Security whitepaper](http://images.apple.com/iphone/business/docs/iOS_Security_Oct12.pdf), files are encrypted by per file encryption keys and those are encrypted by class keys assigned by the application that owns the files (which are sandboxed with the application). And then, the files access depends on the protection policy you assigned in your application.

However, from this [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/ios-encryption-details), it is unclear if the encryption is always on, or just when the device if off or unlocked.

In any case, the above applies from non jailbreaked systems (not sure if they do for jailbreaked ones as well).